# UITableView scroll horizontal (to right or left)

Tags: iphone

I display about 8 images in a per row of UITableView. But iphone width is enough for 3 or 4 images. How can I scroll UITableView to right and left to see others?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes.
You can use UI scroll View inside tableview cell for row index.

Answer (score 2):

Subclass a UITableCellView and place a UIScrollView inside it.